# How to send answer packets to initial NIC in Windows 2008?

Tags: linux, networking, windows-server-2008, gateway, interface

There are two hosts. Both has two NICs.

```
[host1] -- lan -- [host2]
   |                 |
internet          internet
```

**host1** - Win Server 2008

**host2** - Linux Debian

How to route tcp connections to **host1** through **host2** from the internet?

The problem is the **host1** anwers to internet NIC instead lan NIC via default gateway.

Comment: Why is host1 connected to the WAN if you don't want it to have direct internet access?

Comment: I want direct access to WAN. But I need to receive connections through host2 too.